# Linked List outputs 1 too many?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm making a singly linked list and I'm making an add to beginning node. Whenever I run my tester it works, but it adds (what I assume) an extra node at the beginning with the address.

tester:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linkedlist.h"

using namespace std;

void test01() {

  LinkedList < int > A;

  cout << endl << endl; 
  cout << " ***************** " << endl;
  cout << " *  TEST SET #1  * " << endl;
  cout << " ***************** " << endl;


  cout << "Is the list empty? " << boolalpha << A.isEmpty() <<endl; 
  cout << A << endl;
  cout << "Size of A = " << A.size() << endl;

  //TEST : Inserting 10 numbers to a
  cout << endl << "TEST : Inserting 10 numbers to A" << endl;
  for (int k=0; k<10; k++)
  {
    A.insert_front(k+1);
  } 
  cout << A << endl;
  cout << "Size of a = " << A.size() << endl;

  //TEST : Clearing A
  cout << endl << "TEST : Clearing A" << endl;
  A.clear();
  cout << A << endl;
  cout << "Size of A = " << A.size() << endl << endl;


  cout << "Test 01 - Done!" << endl;
} // Destructor Called Here!!

int main () {

  cout << "Hello World!!, This is the LinkedList LARGE Tester" << endl; 

  test01();


  cout << "LARGE Done!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

LinkedList.hpp (what i'm allowed to modify)

```
#include "linkedlist.h"

 // --------
 // ---- Basic Accessor Operations ---
 // --------
 // Purpose: accessor function for the current # data values in the list
 // Returns: current size of the list
 template <class T>
 int LinkedList<T>::size() const
 {
 }

  // Purpose: puts the data x in the front of the list 
  // Parameters: x is data value to inserted
  // Postconditions: x is the first element of the list
 template <class T>
 void LinkedList<T>::insert_front(const T& x)
 {
  if(m_next == NULL)
  {
   m_next = new LinkedList<T>;
   m_next->m_data = x;
   m_next->m_next = NULL;
  }

  LinkedList<T> *temp;
  temp = new LinkedList<T>;
  temp->m_data = x;
  temp->m_next = m_next;
  m_next = temp;

 }
```

LinkedList.h (not allowed to modify)

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
  T m_data;                // Data to be stored
  LinkedList<T>* m_next;      // Pointer to the next element in the list
  static T m_objerr;

    // Purpose: Default constructor
    // Postconditions: next pointer set to NULL
    // -INLINE-
  LinkedList() : m_next(NULL) {}

    // Purpose: Auxiliaty constructor, construct from parameters
    //     useful when inserting elements
    // Postconditions: data and next pointer set to parameters
    // -INLINE-
  LinkedList(const T& x, LinkedList<T>* p) 
             : m_data(x), m_next(p) {}

   void insert_front(const T& x);

   int size() const;

}
```

After compiling the list `cout` is correct but theres an added node at the beginning that contains the address location for that node. I tried quite a few ways but none of them seem to remove that last node no matter what.

Comment: Your class is incomplete, you should apply the Rule of Three.  As far as I can see you have at least one memory leak.

Comment: Is that 1:1 the real code? This shouldn’t even compile (actually, it should compile, but not link) – you cannot just dump template code into a separate compilation unit.

Comment: I suggest you save time and frustration and go with the STL `list`.  It's already been written and verified so you don't have to.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see what happens when you add the very first node to the list:

```
template <class T>
 void LinkedList<T>::insert_front(const T& x)
 {
     if(m_next == NULL) // m_next is NULL
     {
        // ok, let's add the first node

        m_next = new LinkedList<T>;
        m_next->m_data = x;
        m_next->m_next = NULL; // this line isn't neccesary, the default constructor
                               // called in the new expression above took care of that
        // you should utilize the other constructor and say
        // m_next = new LinkedList<T>(x, m_next);

        // ok, done, let's continue with the code below
     }

     // Wait a second! We already added a node, what are we doing here?

     LinkedList<T> *temp;
     temp = new LinkedList<T>;
     temp->m_data = x;
     temp->m_next = m_next;
     m_next = temp;
 }
```

So every time you add the first node, you're actually adding two. The rest of insertions work fine since the `if` condition isn't true anymore. 
To fix it, you can either wrap the second part of code in `else` block or add a `return` statement inside the `if` block.

Note that, with the way you're currently handling things, the whole `insert_front` method can be shortened to

```
m_next = new LinkedList<T>(x, m_next);
```

I can see some issues with the design of this, though. The class itself acts as a container and a node at the same time. Usualy linked list implementations use a separate class for the nodes and the actual container class just holds a pointer to the first node (and probably members to cache the size and tail, etc...). Another problem is the default constructor and the way you insert the first node. Currently a default constructed list holds undefined `m_data` as the first node. The very first insertion of a node should probably just set `m_data` to desired value and set `m_next` to NULL.

Comment: when i wrap the second part in an else the first node gets removed for some reason. so when cout it desplays 5,4,3,2] instead of 5,4,3,2,1]

Comment: @T.J.Williams checked, it works for me, maybe it's the way you're iterating/printing the list.

Comment: so when this prints, you get 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1? when i cout it prints some random address, 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2

Comment: as it is now, m_data will always be node 1. do you happen to know a way around this? or maybe to have the second part (outside of m_next ==NULL) skip the first time its called?